# iOS CoreData inverse relationships to itself

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, inverse

I am trying to build a CoreData model similar to Twitter user when User can have many other users who follows him and many other users followed by him. I attached the model that I have tried to use but seems it is getting to complicating to retrieve followers. 
What is the best way to deal with this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to create a second relationship (`followedBy`) and make that the inverse.

Comment: So that following and followedBy point to each other as many-to-many relationships?