# Core Data NSValidationErrorObject, causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm working on an app where I have Users, each User have a many-to-many relationship to followers. I'm currently having some problems with saving new user objects. The app craches on  `managedObjectContext save`. I get the following error:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "The operation couldn’t be   completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)" UserInfo=0x8580640 {NSDetailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed.  (Cocoa error 1550.)\" UserInfo=0x85820c0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<User: 0x7575870> (entity:  User; id: 0x75757c0 

NSValidationErrorKey=followers, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.), NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'followers' on managed object (0x7575870) <User: 0x7575870> (entity: User; id: 0x75757c0 
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)\" UserInfo=0x8586830 {NSValidationErrorObject=<User: 0x7571ec0> (entity: User; id: 0x7571f00 

"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)\" UserInfo=0x858e820 {NSValidationErrorObject=<User: 0x7573120> (entity: User; id: 0x7573160  

[...]
```

I can't really figure out what is causing this crash. My relationship looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The model have a custom NSManagedObject subclass with the `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *followers;`. As I said, I'm not really sure what is causing this, so any guidance or ideas would be great!

**Update**

The app crashes in this method:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You   should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            // Uncomment "abort" makes it work, but I still get the error. 
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

More code from my models and how it use them:

How I set up my fetch request controller:

```
- (NSSortDescriptor *)sortDescriptorForFetchRequest
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    if ([self.postType isEqualToString:@"following"] || [self.postType isEqualToString:@"followers"]) {
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userId" ascending:NO];
    } else {
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postId" ascending:NO];
    }

    return sortDescriptor;
}

- (NSEntityDescription *)entityForFetchRequest
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity;
    if ([self.postType isEqualToString:@"followers"] || [self.postType isEqualToString:@"following"]) {
        entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[self.appController managedObjectContext]];
    } else {
        entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:[self.appController managedObjectContext]];
        }

    return entity;
}

- (void)setUpFetchResultController
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[self entityForFetchRequest]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[self predicateBasedOnPostType:self.postType]];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[self sortDescriptorForFetchRequest]];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self.appController managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:[self cacheName]];
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

And my model, `User`:

```
+ (void)addUserFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary forUser:(User *)user  inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc follower:(BOOL)follower following: (BOOL)following
{
    User *localUser;
    if (follower) {
        if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictionary objectEnumerator];
            id value;
            while (value = [enumerator nextObject]) {
                localUser = [self parseUserFromDictionary:value inManagedObjectContext:moc];

               if ([self user:localUser alreadyFollowingUser:user inManagedObjectContext:moc] == NO) {
                   [user addFollowersObject:localUser];
                   [localUser addFollowingObject:user];
              }   
            }
        }
    }
}

+ (User *)parseUserFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber * userId = [numberFormatter numberFromString:(NSString *)[dictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];

    User *user;

    if ([self userAlreadyExist:userId inManagedObjectContext:moc] == NO) {
        NSEntityDescription *userDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        user = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:userDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
    } else {
        user = [User findUser:userId inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    }

    user.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
    [...]    
    return user;
}
```

Comment: What does the relation User->following look like? It looks like you set some contraints which aren't satisfied

Comment: It looks the same as followers. Wrong picture.

Comment: Are you sure you have cleaned you app and everything and that your sqlite file matches your defined xcdatamodeld file? I do not see an error in the code and scheme you provided.

Comment: @RobinvanDijke Yes, I have tried both to delete the application and use "Reset contents...", but no difference. I think it's pretty strange that it's not working. I have used the same data model before, got this error recently. Could the error be caused outside the model?

Comment: And cleaned your XCode build before compiling? I'm not sure but the only causes I can think of are constraints on the relation User->Followers or not cleaned sqlite. As I mentioned, I cannot see the error in the code and screenshots you provided. If you want me to dig deeper into it you have to provide some more code/model-data which can contain the error

Comment: Yes, cleaned and all. I have added some more code to my original question.

Comment: Are those the complete error messages? I've never seen them end without closing brackets and parentheses. If not, could you post the complete error?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have updated my original question now!

Comment: Thanks, but it's still hard to tell what's wrong. You might find this discussion useful though: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/190768-validation-error-in-relationship-in-coredata.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a hunch: Is the relationship between objects in different MOCs? Strange things can happen if you do that!

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced your code and datamodel in a separate project. I thought that it could be a cycle in your data or something so I tried all of the following code:

```
[userA addFollowersObject:userB];
[userB addFollowingObject:userA];

[userB addFollowersObject:userA];
[userA addFollowingObject:userB];

[userA addFollowersObject:userA];
[userA addFollowingObject:userA];

[userB addFollowingObject:userB];
[userB addFollowersObject:userB];
```

...but saves were valid all the time. The last thing I could think of is multithreading. Are you using multiple threads you are accessing your ManagedObjectContext from? If so, that could cause inconsistencies in your data which causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The secret was the ManagedObjectContext. I made a shared ManagedObjectContext for the app and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Would be helpful if you gave more details on the model definition including `User` and `Followers`. This is a guess but is your inverse for `followers` incorrect?

I would expect to see the relationship in User defined like:

```
M followers    User    following
```

and the relationship in Follower defined like:

```
M following    User    followers
```

Comment: Thaks, I actually only have one main model, `User` which have a many-to-many relationship with itself, `followers`.

Comment: I still think it is wrong for a relationship to have itself as the inverse. I made an edit to have followers/following be inverses to each other.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709842/ios-coredata-inverse-relationships-to-itself

Comment: Changed to your suggestion, but I still get the same error. But if I uncomment `abort();` from my save method, then it works but I get the same error log. I have added my save method to my original question.