# CoreData Father, mother children relationship, Can a CoreData subclass have a same relationship with two subclasses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am so struck with this problem

I have a "Person" Coredata Subclass,

Obviously a Person has a father(Person), mother(Person),Spouse(Person) and Children(List of Persons)

(represented in terms of relationship)

If a person is one of the children of his father he is one of the children of his mother two.

So "children" has to be related to Mother and Father.

I cant do that in Core data, Am I missing anything?
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I added a new entity called Marriage 

NSDate *date;
Person *spouse;
NSOrderedSet<Person *> *children;

It seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CoreData you should know, that it is a rapper for SQLite, so you need to make your relationsships like you would do in SQL.
Person "child" is a n:1 realtion to father and to mother.
Model a new Entity for instance MotherToChild where you could do the mapping like normalization in SQL.

Comment: //Person "child" is a n:1 realtion to father and to mother//
I am not able to do it.

Comment: You have to model the relationships in the entities section of your Coredata editor. Another important point is that you need 2 relationships for every 1:n relation. (See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709842/ios-coredata-inverse-relationships-to-itself)

Comment: I clearly understand it, but a person has two relationship to Mother, Father. While the father has a relationship children to a person and the mother has the same relationship to same children which cant be done in core data.
Two inverse relationships is not possible for children.

Comment: Okay understood your problem. Have you tried to Model a new Entity for instance MotherToChild where you could do the mapping like normalization in SQL?

Comment: That is what I did :) You can give that as an answer

Comment: Okay ;) I edited now the initial answer. Hope it was a help anyway.